# The computational complexity of a variant of algorithm for the TSP (Travelling Salesman Problem)

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, graph-traversal

What is the algorithm's computational complexity for a variant of *the Travelling Salesman Problem*, where every node must be visited ***at least once***, meaning that a node can be visited more than once? (The cycle starts from a specific node and, after passing all nodes (at least once) returns to the start node).

The graph is related to a city, where the edges are roads.

Others could ask a similar question, but nobody gives the computational complexity. I am looking for the computational complexity of an exact algorithm for my problem in terms of the number of nodes or edges.

Comment: It's the same as TSP, in fact you can assume that the graph is complete, and therefore you can still visit each vertex exactly once.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on the complexity in terms of the graph order?

Comment: Essentially the same problem. Just replace the distances c[i,j] by the length of the shortest path from i to j.